# How to provide dynamic values to table tr:nth-child(rowNumber)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a situation where a need to add rows after clicked row in table

For that I know this

```
$('table tr:nth-child(2)').after(tr); // which is working but its static.
```

My requirement is to take row number of clicked row which I am taking with below function

```
$('#data-grid-table-tree').find('tr').click(function () {
    rowNumber = ($(this).index() + 1)
});
```

And now I am using `$('table tr:nth-child(rowNumber)').after(tr);` which throwing below error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child

Why it is? How to use dynamic value for nth:child.

Comment: Use `$('table tr:nth-child(' + rowNumber + ')').after(tr);`

Comment: To bind event use `$('#data-grid-table-tree tr').click`

Comment: Please answer first comment worked for me Thanks.

Comment: see update I have mentioned exact

Comment: Problem is that when I click super parent row it will bring child again these child are parent for some records. so when it bring child for super parent it not updating row no.

Comment: If i get it right, please try this jsfiddle example  -http://jsfiddle.net/t2x4yu91/1/

Comment: Yeah that's correct but it not working fro me as it in jsfiddle

Comment: Can I put the code inside function of getting row no. I tried to put in listOfChilds() but its not getting excecuted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `rowNumber` is variable and you need it's value in the selector use `+`

```
$('table tr:nth-child(' + rowNumber + ')').after(tr);
```

---

You can also use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) as follow

```
$('table tr').eq(rowNumber).after(tr);
```

As the indexing of `eq` starts from zero, there's no need of adding `1` to the index.

```
$('#data-grid-table-tree tr').click(function () {
    rowNumber = $(this).index(); // Removed `+ 1` from here
});
```

---

**Edit:**

You can also use `$(this)` to refer to the element that is clicked and use `after` on it.

```
$('#data-grid-table-tree tr').click(function () {
    // Code here

    $(this).after(tr);
});
```

Comment: When I click last row its inserting row above last. Why how to deal with it

Comment: @SohamShetty `after` should do that. Try `eq`, the second option.

Comment: eq is not doing any thing

Comment: @SohamShetty Can you please create live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net). Also check my edit at the bottom of answer

Comment: If i get it right, please try this jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/t2x4yu91/1/

Answer (score 0):

You bind the click event on the `tr`, why not use that to your advantage. You want to place the new `tr` right after it. So instead of using its index, insert it direct after the clicked element.

```
$('#data-grid-table-tree').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).after(tr);
});
```